# how to format a date in embeddedjs

Tags: mongodb, express, ejs, embedded-javascript

app.js

```
app.get('/user.html', function(req, res){
    dbConnect.collection("users").find().toArray(function(err, docsData) {
        res.render('user', {
            data: docsData,
            title: "EJS example",
            header: "Some users"
        });
    });
});
```

user.html

```
<% data.forEach(function(user){ %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= user.date %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% }) %>
```

output is
2014-12-24T09:47:07.436Z

this is the value coming from mongodb. I want to format this to Dec-24-2014. How to format it in embeddedjs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `toDateString()` to better format date in JavaScript :

```html
<% data.forEach(function(user){ %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= user.date.toDateString() %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% }) %>
```

If you want to display date in a custom format, you can use third party module like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/%20moment.js). Using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/%20moment.js) your code would be like following:

app.js

```js
var moment = require('moment');
app.get('/user.html', function(req, res){
    dbConnect.collection("users").find().toArray(function(err, docsData) {
        res.render('user', {
            data: docsData,
            title: "EJS example",
            header: "Some users",
            moment: moment
        });
    });
});
```

user.html

```html
<% data.forEach(function(user){ %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= moment(user.date).format( 'MMM-DD-YYYY') %>
       </td>
    </tr>
<% }) %>
```

Hope this help!